# How to sum column values with cross-column matching?

Tags: python, pandas

Python Pandas question:

I have a table with 3 columns: From_City, To_City, Trip_Count and 4 rows:

`+-----------+---------+------------+
| From_City | To_City | Trip_Count |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| Berlin    | London  |          2 |
| London    | Berlin  |          3 |
| Sydney    | Tokyo   |          4 |
| Tokyo     | Sydney  |          6 |
+-----------+---------+------------+`

I want to sum trips between cities into a new table that has 2 rows only:

`+--------+------------+------------+
|  City  | Other_City | Trip_Count |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Berlin | London     |          5 |
| Sydney | Tokyo      |         10 |
+--------+------------+------------+`

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this in Python (preferably in Pandas). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Note: Order between two cities doesn't matter. either Berlin-London or London-Berlin is fine.

Comment: In SQL I could do the following, but I'm not sure how to do the same in python:
    `select 
    least(from_city, to_city) as city,
    greatest(from_city, to_city) as other_city,
    sum(trip_count) as trip_count
  from trips
  group by least(from_city, to_city), greatest(from_city, to_city)
`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'From_City': ['Berlin', 'London', 'Sydney', 'Tokyo'], 'To_City': ['London', 'Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Sydney'], 'Trip_Count': [2, 3, 4, 6]})

print df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x[:2].tolist())+[x[2]], axis=1).groupby(['From_City', 'To_City']).sum()
```

result

```
                   Trip_Count
From_City To_City            
Berlin    London            5
Sydney    Tokyo            10
```

Comment: Or even `df.apply(lambda x: [x[1], x[0], x[2]] if x[1] < x[0] else x, axis =1).groupby(['From_City','To_City']).sum()` if we want to economize on words.

Comment: @ptrj Good! Improved my answer little bit based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks @ptrj and su79eu7k.  Both of your methods give me what I want, BUT the resulting dataframe has only 1 column, summed Trip_Count. How do I keep the two GROUPBY columns in the dataframe? I need these columns for later use.

Comment: @reptile_K `df.reset_index()` on a resulting data frame should do it. Or argument `as_index = False` to `groupby`. See [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).